# Cassandra : Batch write optimisation

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

I get bulk write request for let say some 20 keys from client.
I can either write them to C* in one batch or write them individually in async way and wait on future to get them completed.

Writing in batch does not seem to be a goo option as per documentation as my insertion rate will be high and if keys belong to different partitions co-ordinators will have to do extra work.

> Is there a way in datastax java driver with which I can group keys
>   which could belong to same partition and then club them into small
>   batches and then do invidual unlogged batch write in async. IN that
>   way i make less rpc calls to server at the same time coordinator will
>   have to write locally. I will be using token aware policy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your idea is right, but there is no built-in way, you usually do that manually.

Main rule here is to use `TokenAwarePolicy`, so some coordination would happen on driver side.
Then, you could group your requests by equality of partition key, that would probably be enough, depending on your workload.

What I mean by 'grouping by equality of partition key` is e.g. you have some data that looks like

```
MyData { partitioningKey, clusteringKey, otherValue, andAnotherOne }
```

Then when inserting several such objects, you group them by `MyData.partitioningKey`. It is, for all existsing `paritioningKey` values, you take all objects with same `partitioningKey`, and wrap them in `BatchStatement`. Now you have several `BatchStatements`, so just execute them.

If you wish to go further and mimic cassandra hashing, then you should look at cluster metadata via `getMetadata` method in `com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster` class, there is method `getTokenRanges` and compare them to result of `Murmur3Partitioner.getToken` or any other partitioner you configured in `cassandra.yaml`. I've never tried that myself though.

So, I would recommend to implement first approach, and then benchmark your application. I'm using that approach myself, and on my workload it works far better than without batches, let alone batches without grouping.

Comment: How do I batch keys to go to same node ? - does data stax client expose the tokens belonging to every node, so tha i can murmurhash and then group them ?

Comment: can you explain "you could group your requests by equality of partition key" a bit more? I did not understand this part

Comment: Added some detail.

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: I think Hbase driver do this internally datastax should incorporate this incase of bulk  queries

Answer (score 0):

**Logged** batches should be used carefully in Cassandra becase they impose additional overhead. It also depends on the partition keys distribution. If your bulk write targets a single partition then using **Unlogged** batch results in a single insert operation.

In general, writing them invidually in async manner seems to be a good aproach as pointed here:
https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-the-nuanced-edition-dd78d61e9885

You can find sample code on the above site how to handle multiple async writes:
https://gist.github.com/rssvihla/26271f351bdd679553d55368171407be#file-bulkloader-java
https://gist.github.com/rssvihla/4b62b8e5625a805583c1ce39b1260ff4#file-bulkloader-java

**EDIT:**

please read this also:
https://inoio.de/blog/2016/01/13/cassandra-to-batch-or-not-to-batch/#14

> **What does a single partition batch cost?**
>
> There’s no batch log written for single partition batches. The
> coordinator doesn’t have any extra work (as for multi partition
> writes) because everything goes into a single partition. Single
> partition batches are optimized: they are applied with a single
> RowMutation [10].
>
> In a few words: single partition batches don’t put much more load on
> the server than normal writes.

> **What does a multi partition batch cost?**
>
> Let me just quote Christopher Batey, because he has summarized this
> very well in his post “Cassandra anti-pattern: Logged batches” [3]:
>
> Cassandra [is first] writing all the statements to a batch log. That
> batch log is replicated to two other nodes in case the coordinator
> fails. If the coordinator fails then another replica for the batch log
> will take over. [..] The coordinator has to do a lot more work than
> any other node in the cluster.
>
> Again, in bullets what has to be done:
>
> 1. serialize the batch statements
> 2. write the serialized batch to the batch log system table
> 3. replicate of this serialized batch to 2 nodes
> 4. coordinate writes to nodes holding the different partitions
> 5. on success remove the serialized batch from the batch log (also on the 2 replicas)
>
> Remember that unlogged batches for multiple partitions are deprecated since Cassandra 2.1.6